# NFC-list No Device Found (ER301 EUhoyan)

Tags: linux, nfc, rfid

I'm trying to figure out how to use a chinese RFID/NFC device (Euhoyan ER301) on my Kali Linux.

I have installed the libnfc and all the dependencies. But executing the command "NFC-LIST" theres no devices found.

Executing **lsusb** I can see the device:

**"Bus 003 Device 012: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light"**

Apparently the driver **CP210x** is installed too.

I'm not quite sure if it is the good way to communicate with the device and if it is compatible with the libnfc.

Does someone has more experience about this devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have the same issue with 860-960Mhz UHF RFID Reader Writer, it can not be recognized with libnfc, could you solve this?